# Running unit tests in Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to set up CI/CD for several Python projects (all GAE/GCF). I can deploy the code just fine but I want to run the entire test suite before the deploy steps. How can I do that? Do I have to setup a whole docker build step in order to get this done or is there a simpler way?

Comment: May be custom build step using a docker image? https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'docker build . --tag my_app']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'docker tag my_app:latest eu.gcr.io/my_project/my_app']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'docker push eu.gcr.io/my_project/my_app']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'docker run my_app pytest']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app.yaml', '--image-url=eu.gcr.io/my_project/my_app:latest']
```

I build and tag my container image. Then I push it up to Google Cloud Repo. Then I run my tests with `pytest` and then I deploy to Google Cloud Engine.

Answer (score 0):

The main point here is to use the `entrypoint: 'bash'` option for the test step. Same as original answer but pointing out that it's not required for all other steps.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'myimage', '.']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker run myimage npm run test']
```